# ¿Cómo modificar el ancho de columna en un documento .xlsx generado con SheetJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sheetjs

Estoy intentando descargar mi tabla HTML en formato .xlsx, por lo que he seguido [este](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFK5dXNauGs) tutorial de la [librería SheetJS](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx). Y funciona, el .xlsx se generó y descargó, pero ahora necesito personalizar esa tabla empezando por el ancho de las columnas, pues está en el ancho predeterminado y es demasiado pequeño, por lo que los datos no se muestran correctamente.

He intentado con [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395693/how-to-set-cell-width-when-export-xlsx-files-with-js-xlsx) solución, pero no funciona.

Pueden ver el código y descargar el archivo .xlsx generado en el siguiente snipet:

```js
function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}
function doexcel(){
 var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById("miTabla"),{sheet:"Sheet 1"}) //my html table
 
 var wbcols = [
  {wpx:149},
  {wpx:200}
 ];

 wb['!cols'] = wbcols;   // THIS IS NOT WORKING

 var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx',  bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});
 saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), 'GeneradoConSheetJS.xlsx');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7" />
<title>Excel Test</title>

<!-- JQuery  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- minified sheetjs -->
<script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.12.11/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<!-- minified FileSaver -->
<script lang="javascript" src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(Principal);
function Principal(){
  $(document).on("click","#btnexcel", function(){doexcel()});
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btnexcel">Download excel</button>
<table id="miTabla">
  <thead><tr><th>Hola</th><th>Mi gente hermosa</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Mi nombre real es</td><td>Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Esta tabla es</td><td>generada dinámicamente</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Como pueden ver, estoy tratando de establecer el ancho de la columna a 149 y 200 px (tal vez afectará las dos primeras columnas), pero el archivo .xlsx descargado mantiene su ancho predeterminado de columna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se aprecia que los datos no se muestran correctamente, ya que el ancho de las columnas no se ajusta al texto.

¿Qué me podría estar faltando?

Acepto sugerencias de hacer esto de cualquier otra manera, necesito generar y personalizar un archivo .xlsx idealmente con javascript o jquery. Mi backend es con php pero he visto que [phpExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) está obsoleto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** el array de columnas va en cada sheet (hoja)

```
 wb["Sheets"]["Sheet 1"]["!cols"] = [{ wpx : 149 },{ wpx : 200 }];
```

```js
function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}
function doexcel(){
 var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById("miTabla"),{sheet:"Sheet 1"}) //my html table
 
  wb["Sheets"]["Sheet 1"]["!cols"] = [{ wpx : 149 },{ wpx : 200 }];
      
   console.log(wb);
   
 var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx',  bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});
 saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), 'GeneradoConSheetJS.xlsx');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7" />
<title>Excel Test</title>

<!-- JQuery  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- minified sheetjs -->
<script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.12.11/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<!-- minified FileSaver -->
<script lang="javascript" src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(Principal);
function Principal(){
  $(document).on("click","#btnexcel", function(){doexcel()});
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btnexcel">Download excel</button>
<table id="miTabla">
  <thead><tr><th>Hola</th><th>Mi gente hermosa</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Mi nombre real es</td><td>Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Esta tabla es</td><td>generada dinámicamente</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**2** phpexcel tiene sucesor en phpspreadsheet

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

segun la documentación en:
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/

para darle el ancho:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(12);
```

para que tome ancho automático;

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Sabes dónde puedo aprender mejor a usar SheetJS? La documentación no me lo deja muy claro y aun me cuesta algo el inglés.

Comment: es medio prueba y error, la documentación esta muy completa pero muchas veces falta el contexto de cada demo y hay que ver el código fuente de la página. una vez que lo vas usando y probando empieza a tener sentido, pero así de entrada si, esta medio demasiado técnico.

Comment: Gracias a ese console.log(wb) que pusiste, he podido estudiar mejor la librería. Pero sigo sin poder añadir bordes a las celdas, he intentado algo como wb["Sheets"]["Sheet1"]["A1"]["s"] = {"border":"1px"}; pero no da resultado, podrías atender esta duda en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160813/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-borde-a-las-celdas-de-un-documento-xlsx-generado-con-sheetjs?noredirect=1#comment302178_160813 por favor?