# Cómo agregar borde a las celdas de un documento .xlsx generado con SheetJS?

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

Tengo un archivo .xlsx generado con [SheetJS](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx), pero no he podido poner el borde en las celdas.

Tengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo? No importa la biblioteca, solo tiene que ser con JavaScript.

.

**EDIT**

Dejo parte del código .js que he intentado, genera la tabla pero no aplica los estilos a la celda que estoy especificando (A1), en la documentación aparece que la key "s" de un cell object contiene el estilo o tema de la celda, por eso he intentado esto:

```
function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}
function creaExcel(){
    var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById("myTable"),{sheet:"Sheet 1"}) //my html table

    wb["Sheets"]["Sheet 1"]["A1"]["s"] = [{ "border" : "1px" },{ "background" : "rgb(90,60,30)" }];

    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx',  bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});
    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), 'PlanillaConSheetJS.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: Hola Roberto, incluye el código que actualmente esta utilizando para la exportación

Comment: @ManuelMorales ya puedes ver el .js que he intentado.

Comment: la versión oficial aún no soporta estilos, hay un fork https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style  y un pull request https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/pull/263

Comment: @aloMalbarez está interesante la sección "Cell Styles" en la documentación, me gustaría mucho aplicar esos borders, pero no me queda claro cómo hacerlo. Estaré intentando, aviso si me sale algo.